# Splitting YYYYMMDD date into 3 parts in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, datetime

How do I split a date that is of the form YYYYMMDD into its constituents?

```
my ($yyyy, $mm, $dd) = $date =~ /(\4d+)(\2d+)(\2d+)/;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
my ($year, $month, $day) = unpack "A4A2A2", $date;
```

`pack` and `unpack` are underused builtins that can be used to great power.

Comment: unpack is the fastest perl has to offer, especially for fixed-width data.

Comment: can you do error checking with unpack? for ex: have an or 'die "Wrong format"' statement after that?

Comment: great power but poor validation

Comment: @ysth: using a regexp doesn't properly validate either. It will allow 9999-99-99 as a date, even though that clearly isn't a valid date.

Comment: It depends on how `$date` is being stored, `unpack` is only good for fixed width.  Given my example, if there's any other text other than 8 digits (even spaces), then `unpack` will break.  That's why my answer adds some pre-validation, using `\b`.

Comment: @Leon Timmermans: yes, but it's a good first step; at least you know your variables are numeric can treat them as such.

Answer (score 4):

```
my ($year, $month, $day) = $date =~ /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\z/a
    or die "bad date: $date";
```

Comment: maybe `$` was meant instead of `\z`?

Comment: Could i use o instead? I'm using it two other times (not in a loop though)

Comment: @syker: please see [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for details about regular expression syntax (e.g. what the z, $, \d and other components mean).

Comment: @syker: @jdehaan: `$` would mean either the end of the string or \n and then the end of the string.  Since the specified format shouldn't have a \n, I used \z

Comment: @syker: o isn't relevant here - I don't understand what you are proposing it replace

Comment: Note that `\d` matches any Unicode digits, not just latin decimal digits. So if you want to do input validation use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

   sub main{
      my $date = "some text with the numbers 2010063011 and more text";
      print "Input Date: $date\n";

      my ($year, $month, $day) = $date =~ /\b(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\b/;      
      print qq{
               Date:  $date
               Year:  $year
               Month: $month
               Day:   $day\n} if (defined $year && defined $month && defined $day);
   }

   main();
```

notice this will look for the first date in the regex, it won't work with `2010063011` because it's not a date, but it will work with `20100630`, which is what you want.

Comment: your method vs the unpack method makes sense, thanks for adding that comment in the `unpack` answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to work with dates I use the DateTime module. You can grab it from CPAN.

Answer (score -1):

Note that \d matches any Unicode digits, not just latin decimal digits.

So if you want to do input validation use '[0-9]' instead of  '\d'.